Create array by combining neighbouring pairs of items
I have the following array of four elements:
arr = [{"location": 10, "value": 50}, {"location": 21, "value": 70}, {"location": 33, "value": 20}, {"location": 48, "value": 0}]

I would like to create a new array of three elements combining adjacent items: [ {index 0, 1}, {index 1, 2}, {index 2, 3} ]
The function to run on each pair is simple:
def combine(current, next):
    return (next["location"] - current["location"]) * current["value"]

Obviously, this can be done using a loop, but is there a more pythonic way of achieving this?
I would like to generate the following output:
[550, 840, 300]  // (21 - 10) * 50, (33 - 21) * 70, (48 - 33) * 20


You can use zip(arr, arr[1:]):
def get_combine_neighbors(A):
    _comb = lambda x, y: (y["location"] - x["location"]) * x["value"]
    return [_comb(x, y) for x, y in zip(A, A[1:])]


A = [{"location": 10, "value": 50}, {"location": 21, "value": 70},
     {"location": 33, "value": 20}, {"location": 48, "value": 0}]
print(get_combine_neighbors(A))


Prints
[550, 840, 300]


I would first extract a proper numpy array from your list then the computation of the result is immediate.
import numpy as np

data = np.array([list(d.values()) for d in arr]).T
res = (arr[0, 1:] - arr[0, :-1]) * arr[1, :-1]

print(res)

Output:
array([550, 840, 300])


r = [(arr[i+1]['location']-arr[i]['location'])*arr[i]['value']\
for i in range(len(arr)) if i != len(arr) - 1 ]

print(r) # Output : [550, 840, 300]

